# Refering to a single object in a collection in a association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to refer to a single object in a collection in a association from the controller to view, ie the controller action looks like this

```
VideosController

  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @videos = @user.videos
 end
```

and index view

```
<% if @videos.any? && @videos[0].playlist_value == 0 || nil %>
do stuff
<% end %>

<% else %>
....
```

The problematic bit is the `@videos[0].playlist_value == 0 || nil` once I wack that part in rails skips to the `else` statement.

For record the database value is `nil` for `playlist_value` attribute so this statement should be working except I cannot reference the object correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the object reference problem. It's your value check.

```
@videos[0].playlist_value == 0 || nil
```

This does NOT mean "if playlist value equals 0 or equals nil". Spell it out explicitly:

```
@videos[0].playlist_value == 0 || @videos[0].playlist_value == nil
```

or

```
@videos[0].playlist_value.in?([0, nil])
```

or

```
[0, nil].include?(@videos[0].playlist_value)
```

or

```
 @videos[0].playlist_value.to_i == 0
```

or maybe 10 other ways.